# New Crassula ovata gollum (aka jade) plant leaves shrinking blackened and dropping

Tags: succulents, jade

I recently bought **Crassula Ovata gollum** from online. The leaves look shrunk and blackening from tip and starting to fall. Guessing that the soil mix is(garden soil+perlite+organic materials. I water it 3-4 days once (i thought it needs some water). Need help to understand its state.[image]